# tkinter rewriting a widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having trouble understanding the update() method. I thoguht when I use [widget].update() the widget is supposed to recreate itself (or if I use root.update() all widgets in root recreate themselves).
But my program does not do that. What is the simplest way to recreate a widget? I can obviously use configure on labels and stuff but it does not work on OptionMenus right? So how to I recreate widgets like Optionmenus?

```
from tkinter import *

def f1():
    menu = menu = OptionMenu(root, var, "hello", "hi", "hey")
    menu.update() # or root.update()

root = Tk()

var = StringVar()
var.set("hello")
menu = OptionMenu(root, var, "hello", "hi")
menu.pack()

button = Button(root, text="button", command=f1)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what do you actually want it to do?

Comment: you understand correctly what update does, but in your function you are creating a new variable menu which is a new OptionMenu widget and you didn't packed it into your root.  Also even if you had done `global menu` before it wouldn't work because putting a new widget in a variable is not the same as changing something from the variable, You could though destroy the widget and put a new one in its place, but it would not work properly with pack.

Comment: @FlavioMoraes: no, the understanding of `update` is completely wrong. Also, the statement "it would not work properly with pack" is incorrect. `pack` can be used, you just have to have an understanding of how `pack` works and how to use all of its options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thoguht when I use [widget].update() the widget is supposed to recreate itself

No, that's not what `update` does at all.

Tkinter applications (as well as any GUI written with any toolkit) relies on a steady flow of events - mouse clicks, button clicks, mouse movement, requests from the operating system to redraw, etc. These events are placed on a queue by the operating system, and tkinter uses `mainloop` to pull those events off one by one to process them.

`update` is merely a request for `mainloop` pull off all pending events and process them. It is independent of any specific widget.

> So how to I recreate widgets like Optionmenus?

If you want to recreate a widget, it is up to your code to destroy and recreate the widget. The process is the same as when you originally created it.

Here's an example starting with the code in the question:

```
def f1():
    global menu
    menu.destroy()
    menu = OptionMenu(root, var, "hello", "hi", "hey")
    menu.pack(before=button)
```

This means that you have to plan ahead to make sure it's easy to recreate the widget. `pack` makes that more difficult since by default it places things in the order in which `pack` was called. In the above example, the code uses the `before` option to make sure the new menu goes before the button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete all the options and, add the old and new ones in again.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
root = Tk()

def f1():
    var.set('hello')
    menu['menu'].delete(0, 'end')

    options = ("hello", "hi", "hey")
    for i in options:
        menu['menu'].add_command(label=i, command=tk._setit(var, i))

var = StringVar()
var.set("hello")
menu = OptionMenu(root, var, "hello", "hi")
menu.pack()

button = Button(root, text="button", command= f1)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```